# Multiple leads with conflicting interests? How to manage them?

Tags: colleagues, leadership

I have been recruited for a Project by my current Organization. This Organization is client for my Employer. My Employer is vendor to this Organization.  This project belongs to a Department, Lets name it as B. How ever this Kind of project was successfully handled in the past by Department A. So Director assigns responsibilities of initial setup, team building and building base for the project to Department B and Department A take over one point.

I have been placed as Senior developer for this project since from starting of the project. Eventually I have to take lead role for this project. Department A has 2 Leads, Let us name them AL1, AL2 And Department B has 2 other leads, Let us name them as BL1, BL2. Total 4 Leads.

The Department A laid the following plan. Release1 Lead by AL1, Release2 Lead by AL2. With in these 2 releases Department A setup every thing required for Department B and then handover to Department B. Department B will take over from there and plans further

Now we are in Release2. Now I am seeing difference in their interests. AL1 was  more concerned about building strong base and managing rest of the things. I followed him closely on Release1 and he supported me, mentored me and helped me much. He is employee of Current Organization.

Now AL2 take in charge. AL2 is also Contractor and he is from different vendor. He is more protective, helpful to other team members who are also employees of his employer. But he is protecting and supporting nominally for other vendors. Some of his methods and approaches are direct conflict with AL1.

AL1 and AL2 privately and personally suggesting keep distance with BL1 and BL2 and suggesting don't simply accept their suggested changes without strong reason.

In the meanwhile BL2 is trying to build good relationship with me by inviting me for outside Coffee/lunch etc.. and asking my cooperation for some of the areas. BL1 is not  engaging any of these activities. But For any kind request/idea he is very formal. Very stringent for negotiations/changes. It is always impossible all these 4 guys on the same page and in agreement.

I am now confused and scare how to handle them. It is very difficult to make them all happy at the same time. I am struggling very much not to be bad on any one. It is very hard for me to oblige all these 4 Leads at the same time.

How to handle this situation professionally? How to manage all these leads with out disappoint anyone or without any negative feelings?

Answer (score 1):

Focus on the requirements and the deliverables.  And build positive relationships. It may be that you can't make everyone happy in what sounds like a politically charged environment so focus your time on the most important of the relationships that are needed to deliver on your project.

I would encourage you to build open relationships with those involved while watching for hidden agendas. I would also argue that any project change, no matter who suggests, should be well considered so you avoid feature creep or direction changes that impact the ability to complete your project on budget and on time.